# Foxit Reader Facing View

Tags: pdf, foxit-reader

In Foxit Reader, there is a "Facing View" that allows you to view 2 pages side by side, like a book.  It shows page 1 next to page 2.  Advance 1 page, it shows 3 next to 4.  The problem I am having is that the I want it to start on an even number page.  So I would see 2 on the left and 3 on the right.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable "Separate cover page" mode. This mode works with facing view to give you even numbers on the left for PDFs that have a cover page.

[image: Foxit Reader Separate Cover Page mode]

Comment: That did it.  now the diagrams are correctly showing.